# How can I visualize the scheduling domains on Linux?

Tags: linux, scheduling

It seems current versions of Linux use [scheduling domains](https://lwn.net/Articles/80911/) to distribute processes between CPUs, hyperthreads, NUMA nodes, etc.

Say I wanted to visualize the domains that exist on a system, and some statistics about them that relate to how work is being distributed among them. Questions might be things like:

- What domains exist on this system?
- Is each NUMA node / physical core / other domain being utilized evenly or are processes contending for access to some cores while others are underutilized?
- How frequently are processes being migrated?

What tools are available for such needs?

Answer (score 2):

- For the arrangement of logical CPUs into NUMA nodes:

  ```
  lscpu
  ```

  or:

  ```
  numactl --hardware
  ```

  which also displays real-time information about nodes memory, and node "distances".
- For general info about memory usage by a process:

  ```
  numastat -p <PID_or_name_pattern>
  ```

  from package `numactl`.
- For a much more elaborate tool:

  ```
  numatop
  ```

  (according to the manpage, it supports only Intel Xeon and some IBM processors)

Note that I would be very surprised to see idle cores while the next ones are drowning in work (unless you forced the system into this with cpuset, of course): you can check in a glimpse with a simple `top`, hit `1` for per-CPU activity.

Comment: This is useful information for NUMA but I'm afraid doesn't show much about scheduling domains more generally, for example as it relates to hyperthreading.

Answer (score 0):

The tool made by JP Lozi for his 2016 paper  "The Linux Scheduler: a Decade of Wasted Cores" are available at https://github.com/jplozi/wastedcores
if something like that is what you were looking for.
Various graph output from different benchmark runs are at
http://sfu.lozi.org/results/

I can't vouch for its usability, I haven't used it. Looks like it was last updated for the 4.1 Linux kernel.